# jQuery: Code working on fiddle not working on site

Tags: jquery, debugging

On this site [testsite](http://eslangel.com/66-2/), I'm making a numbers game for ESL students. It uses a flash and a html5 audio player depending on browser (The plugin for somereason uses flash for firefox, but that's not really important). There are 16 audio tracks. The flash player divs are #f-ONE, #f-TWO etc, while the html5 are #ONE, #TWO etc.

All the audio players are hidden on page load, and then (using the working code from this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/9BcUP/)  when you click the start button, one number from an array of 16 is selected and assigned to variable `ran` and then either `#f-` is added if it's flash or `#` is added if html5 and then one of the audio players is supposed to show. `ran.show():` but it doesn't work.

For debugging, I put in some console.log(ran) and it shows that the random element from the array is selected and then the div # is being added, but for someone reason the audio player is not showing.

Can you help me figure out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that your markup is:

```
<audio controls="" autobuffer="" id="SIX" class="html5audio">
    <source src="http://eslangel.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/six.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" name="f-SIX" style="outline-style: none; outline-width: initial; outline-color: initial; visibility: visible; " data="http://eslangel.com/wp-content/plugins/degradable-html5-audio-and-video/incl/player.swf" width="290" height="24" id="f-SIX"><param name="wmode" value="opaque"><param name="menu" value="false"><param name="flashvars" value="initialvolume=80&amp;soundFile=http://eslangel.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/six.mp3&amp;playerID=f-SIX"></object>
    <script type="text/javascript">AudioPlayer.embed("f-SIX", {soundFile: "http://eslangel.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/six.mp3"});</script>
</audio>
```

**Note** that the element with `id='f-SIX'` is *inside* the element with `id='SIX'`. This means that when you hide elements with `id="NUM"`, the element with `id='F-NUM'` is also hidden. Showing the inner element will not cause it to show up because the parent element is hidden (**at least this appears to be the case for Google Chrome**)

Additionally, you have to think about browsers for which only the elements with `id='f-SIX'` are going to show up. This occurs because the `audio` tag is not supported in some browsers yet, therefore just the `object` tag will show up.

I would change your JavaScript as follows:

```
$(".start").click(function() {

    var ran = getRandom(myArray, true);
    if ($('#ONE').length) { 
        ran = $('#' + ran);
        ran.show();

    } else {
        ran = $('#f-' + ran);
        ran.css('display', 'block');
    }
});
```

Also note the use of `display:block` instead of `.show()`. The only reason for this is because I couldn't get the `object` tag to play nice with `.show()` (any advice on this appreciated).

For anyone reading, please read the entire [chat transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/1641) to see how I came about this answer.

Comment: thanks, I think that would only apply to the flash player, whose id="f-SIX" is inside id="SIX". In Chrome, for example, there is no id="f-SIX" so the inside/outside problem doesn't exist. Actually, I don't think you're answer is correct, because when I hid id="SIX" in Chrome it didn't hide id="f-SIX" in firefox...

Comment: o.k, i'll take a closer look again. Thank you. I"m sure you're right. You're a lot more experienced than I am!

Comment: @Michael: Hmm, you're right about different things happening in different browsers. I see no id="SIX" in FireFox...

Comment: ..the audio plugin creates an id #f-ONE for firefox.  Anyways, for the purpose of figuring out the problem,  I removed the code that hides the #f-ONE divs (so in firefox 16 players should show), therefore, there is nothing that should theoretically stop the program from working in Chrome. In Chrome, the divs in format #ONE, #TWO are hidden with CSS and then, according to your fiddle code, one of them should show once you click start.

Comment: @Michael: I'm beginning to think that `.show()` and `hide()` act unpredictably on the `object` tag. Is there any way you could wrap both objects with one `div` that you show and hide instead?

Comment: I think your suggestion would involve altering the plugin code which is very complex.  Anyways, I have no idea what's happening now. I removed the jquery that was hiding the flash players in firefox but they are still hidden.

Comment: @Michael let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1641/discussion-between-andrew-whitaker-and-michael)

Comment: The game you helped me with is finished and working, except now that the audio players don't show in IE. I think when you were helping me, you got the audio players to show in your IE. If you have a moment and are willing to help with the last push to the finish, I have a question/bounty here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6883544/jquery-cross-browser-problem-debugging-internet-explorer  @Andrew Whitaker

Comment: -thanks a lot. If it wasn't clear already, you can see how the game's supposed to work in Chrome, Firefox or Safari.

Comment: I think I figured out what the problem is but don't know how to fix it. Do you remember how we configured things so that the player would work in firefox? I think that has created a situation where it's forcing IE to try to use the html5, which isn't working.

Comment: @Michael: Sorry, I haven't had a chance to take a look at your new question yet. I'll take a look when I get a few minutes.

Comment: no worries. I'm just providing information in case you get a chance. You have already given me a tonne of help (which you weren't required to do)...please don't stretch yourself to help me. I'm just letting you know in case you are interested in helping figure out the problem.