# jQuery: Cross-browser problem -- Debugging Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, audio-streaming

Update: The issue seems to be that due to the JavaScript that was written to acccomodate a problem with Firefox/flash, the program is now trying to play html5 in IE, which isn't working for IE 8 and earlier. However, if I put a javascript based html5 link in the header http://html5media.info/, the html5 players work in IE 8 but not in any workable way. All the players show at once and start playing automatically. Note, all my students are in Asia so the game sort of has to work in IE 8...

I made a game using jQuery/JavaScript for learners of English as a Second language at [game here](http://eslangel.com/michaels-numbers-game/). It works in Chrome, Firefox and Safari, but not Internet Explorer.  I don't know how to figure out the problem in I.E., but it seems like a pretty simple javascript problem that the cross-browser compatability of jQuery shouldn"t have a problem with,  unless my code is so bad that I've screwed it up somehow (note that I am a relative newbie)

The game uses 16 different audio recordings, so there are 16 different audio players. However, each audio player is hidden using css

```
display: none
```

and then made to reappear with

```
.css('display', 'block');
```

but in IE it's not working

Using JavaScript, I randomly select a number from 1 to 16 and then make one of the audio players visible based on that. It all happens when you click "start" on the game"s home page. However, in I.E., the audio player doesn"t show when I click start. This seems like a fairly basic JavaScript issue that I would have thought jQuery wouldn"t have cross-browser issues with, Note, other parts of the JavaScript appear to work in IE. For example, if you click one of the letters at the bottom of the game, it tells you whether your guess was right or wrong (based on the audio you"re supposed to hear).

I also noticed that in I.E. the page takes a heck of a long time to load (5 minutes later, It still says 16 items remaining at the bottom). I assume those might be the audio players. In other browswers, that doesn't happen.

It's very important for me that the game work in IE because the students I made it for are in Japan, and most of them use IE

Can anyone help me debug this in IE or give me an idea how to debug it in IE?

This is the code that is supposed to make the audio player appear. Depending on whether browser uses Flash or HTML5 (which is detected with the line `if ($('#ONE').length)` ), jQuery then either uses "show" or .css('display', 'block') to make the audio player appear. Assuming IE is choosing flash, then it is using

```
.css('display', 'block')
```

to make the audio player appear (unsuccessfully)

jQuery to make audio player appear

```
function test() {
    $(".start").click(function() {

        ran = getRandom(myArray, true);

            if ($('#ONE').length) { 
            $( '#' + ran ).show();
         } 
            else { 
             $('#f-' + ran).css('display', 'block');

         }

         });
```

Update, this is the PHP file from the audio plugin

```
## WPaudio version
$wpa_version = '3.1';

## Pre-2.6 compatibility (from WP codex)
if ( ! defined( 'WP_CONTENT_URL' ) )
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', get_option( 'siteurl' ) . '/wp-content' );
if ( ! defined( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR' ) )
    define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . 'wp-content' );
if ( ! defined( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL' ) )
    define( 'WP_PLUGIN_URL', WP_CONTENT_URL. '/plugins' );
if ( ! defined( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR' ) )
    define( 'WP_PLUGIN_DIR', WP_CONTENT_DIR . '/plugins' );
if ( ! defined( 'WPAUDIO_URL' ) )
    define( 'WPAUDIO_URL', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/wpaudio-mp3-player' );

## Get WPaudio's options from DB (or create them if not found)
$wpa_options = wpaOptions();

## WP handlers - add WPaudio processing at necessary events
# If it's not an admin page, get everything for the player
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    # Calling scripts
    add_action('init', 'wpaLibraries');
    # Add header action to include CSS and JS vars
    add_action('wp_head', 'wpaHead');
    # Add shortcode for WPaudio player
    add_shortcode('wpaudio', 'wpaShortcode');
    # Add filter for shortcode in excerpt and widgets
    add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');
    add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
    # Add filter for non-shortcode substitutes (including excerpts and widgets)
    if ($wpa_options['wpa_tag_audio']) {
        add_filter('the_content', 'wpaFilter');
        add_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpaFilter');
        add_filter('widget_text', 'wpaFilter');
    }
}
# Add admin
add_action('admin_menu', 'wpa_menu');
# Add track
if ($wpa_options['wpa_track_permalink']) add_action('publish_post', 'wpaPostNew');

function wpaOptions(){
    ## WPA options and defaults
    global $wpa_version;
    $wpa_options = Array(
        'wpa_version' => $wpa_version,
        'wpa_pref_link_mp3' => 0,
        'wpa_tag_audio' => 0,
        'wpa_track_permalink' => 1,
        'wpa_style_text_font' => 'Sans-serif',
        'wpa_style_text_size' => '18px',
        'wpa_style_text_weight' => 'normal',
        'wpa_style_text_letter_spacing' => 'normal',
        'wpa_style_text_color' => 'inherit',
        'wpa_style_link_color' => '#24f',
        'wpa_style_link_hover_color' => '#02f',
        'wpa_style_bar_base_bg' => '#eee',
        'wpa_style_bar_load_bg' => '#ccc',
        'wpa_style_bar_position_bg' => '#46f',
        'wpa_style_sub_color' => '#aaa'
    );
    if ( $wpa_options_db = get_option( 'wpaudio_options' ) ) {
        foreach ( $wpa_options as $key => $value ) {
            if ( isset($wpa_options_db[$key]) ) {
                $wpa_options[$key] = $wpa_options_db[$key];
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        # Get legacy options and remove if they exist
        if ( get_option('wpa_tag_audio') ) {
            foreach ($wpa_options as $key => $value) {
                $wpa_option_old_db = get_option($key);
                if ( $wpa_option_old_db !== false && $wpa_option_old_db !== '' ) {
                    $wpa_options[$key] = $wpa_option_old_db;
                }
                delete_option($key);
            }
        }
        # Create wpaudio_options
        add_option('wpaudio_options', $wpa_options, '', 'no');
        //update_option('wpaudio_options', $wpa_options);
    }
    return $wpa_options;
}

## Built-in libraries
function wpaLibraries(){
    global $wpa_version;
    //wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    //wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js', '1.4.3' );
    if ( version_compare( get_bloginfo( 'version' ), '2.8', '>=' ) ) {
        if ( WP_DEBUG === false ) {
            wp_register_script( 'wpaudio', WPAUDIO_URL . '/wpaudio.min.js', Array('jquery'), $wpa_version, true );
        }
        else {
            wp_register_script( 'wpaudio', WPAUDIO_URL . '/wpaudio.js', Array('jquery'), $wpa_version, true);
        }
        wp_enqueue_script( 'wpaudio' );
    }
    else {
        wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
        add_action('wp_footer', 'wpaFooterForOldVersions');
    }
}

## WPaudio style, jQuery, SWFObject
function wpaHead(){
    global $wpa_options;
    # Put all styles into the _wpaudio settings object
    $style = '';
    foreach ( $wpa_options as $key => $value ) {
        $exploded = explode('_', $key, 3);
        if ( $exploded[1] == 'style' ) {
            $style .= $exploded[2] . ":'$value',";
        }
    }
    $style = trim( $style, ',' );
    $style = '{' . $style . '}';
    # Common JS
    $wpa_pref_link_mp3 = ($wpa_options['wpa_pref_link_mp3']) ? 'true' : 'false';
    $head = "<script type='text/javascript'>/* <![CDATA[ */ var _wpaudio = {url: '" . WPAUDIO_URL . "', enc: {}, convert_mp3_links: $wpa_pref_link_mp3, style: $style}; /* ]]> */</script>";
    echo $head;
}

function wpaFooterForOldVersions() {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="' . WPAUDIO_URL . '/wpaudio.min.js"></script>';
}

# Used only for wpaudio shortcode tags
function wpaShortcode($atts){
    # Convert shortcodes to WPaudio player depending on settings
    extract(shortcode_atts(Array(
        'url' => false,
        'text' => false,
        'dl' => true,
        'autoplay' => false
    ), $atts));
    # If no url, return with nothing
    if (!$url)
        return;
    # Get player HTML and JS
    return wpaLink($url, $text, $dl, $autoplay);
}

# Make WPA link
function wpaLink($url, $text = false, $dl = true, $autoplay = false) {
    $id = uniqid('wpaudio-');
    $class = 'wpaudio';
    $html = '';
    # Handle dl URLs and no dl players
    if ($dl == '0') {
        $js_url = wpaUnicode($url);
        $href = '#';
        $class .= ' wpaudio-nodl';
    }
    elseif (is_string($dl)) {
        $js_url = wpaUnicode($url);
        $href = $dl;
    }
    else {
        $href = $url;
    }
    if (isset($js_url)) {
        $class .= ' wpaudio-enc';
        $html .= "<script type='text/javascript'>_wpaudio.enc['$id'] = '$js_url';</script>";
    }
    # Handle blank text
    if (!$text) {
        $text = basename($url);
        $class .= ' wpaudio-readid3';
    }
    # Autoplay
    if ($autoplay == '1') {
        $class .= ' wpaudio-autoplay';
    }
    $html .= "<a id='$id' class='$class' href='$href'>$text</a>";
    return $html;
}

# Used for audio tags
function wpaFilter($content){
    ## Convert audio tags and links to WPaudio player depending on settings
    $tag_regex = '/\[audio:(.*?)\]/';
    $tag_match = preg_match_all($tag_regex, $content, $tag_matches);
    # Replace audio tags with player links
    if ($tag_match){
        foreach ($tag_matches[1] as $key => $value){
            # This is one tag, first get parameters and URLs
            $params = explode('|', $value);
            $clips = Array('urls' => Array(), 'titles' => Array(), 'artists' => Array());
            $clips['urls'] = explode(',', $params[0]);
            # Process extra parameters if they exist
            for ($i=1; $i<count($params); $i++) {
                # Get the parameter name and value
                $param = explode('=', $params[$i]);
                if ($param[0] == 'titles' || $param[0] == 'artists')
                    $clips[$param[0]] = explode(',', $param[1]);
            }
            # Get player(s)
            $player = '';
            foreach ($clips['urls'] as $ukey => $uvalue) {
                $text = '';
                $text .= (isset($clips['artists'][$ukey])) ? $clips['artists'][$ukey] : '';
                $text .= (isset($clips['artists'][$ukey]) && isset($clips['titles'][$ukey])) ? ' - ' : '';
                $text .= (isset($clips['titles'][$ukey])) ? $clips['titles'][$ukey] : '';
                if (!$text) $text = false;
                $player .= wpaLink($uvalue, $text);
            }
            $content = str_replace($tag_matches[0][$key], $player, $content);
        }
    }
    return $content;
}

# Convert string to unicode (to conceal mp3 URLs)
include 'php-utf8/utf8.inc';
function wpaUnicode($str){
    $uni = utf8ToUnicode(utf8_encode($str));
    $output = '';
    foreach ($uni as $value){
        $output .= '\u' . str_pad(dechex($value), 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
    return $output;
}

## WP admin menu
function wpa_menu() {
    add_options_page('WPaudio Options', 'WPaudio', 'switch_themes', __FILE__, 'wpa_menu_page');
}
function wpa_menu_page() {
    global $wpa_options;
    if ($_POST) {
        # Checkboxes need values
        $wpa_checkboxes = Array(
            'wpa_pref_link_mp3',
            'wpa_tag_audio',
            'wpa_track_permalink'
        );
        foreach ($wpa_checkboxes as $value) {
            $_POST[$value] = (isset($_POST[$value]) && $_POST[$value]) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        # Now process and save all options
        foreach ($wpa_options as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($_POST[$key]) && !is_null($_POST[$key]) && $_POST[$key] !== '')
                $wpa_options[$key] = $_POST[$key];
        }
        update_option('wpaudio_options', $wpa_options);
    }
    wpaOptions();
    ?>
<!-- wpa menu begin -->
<div class="wrap">
<h2>WPaudio Options</h2>
<form method="POST" action="">
<?php wp_nonce_field('update-options'); ?>

<div id="poststuff" class="metabox-holder">
    <div class="meta-box-sortables">
        <div class="postbox">
            <h3 class="hndle"><span>Links</span></h3>
            <div class="inside">
                <ul>
                    <li>WPaudio will always convert links with the <span style="font-family: Courier, Serif">wpaudio</span> class.  You optionally handle ALL mp3 links too.</li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_pref_link_mp3"><input name="wpa_pref_link_mp3" id="wpa_pref_link_mp3" type="checkbox" <?php if ($wpa_options['wpa_pref_link_mp3']) echo ' checked="yes"'; ?>>
                        Convert all mp3 links - <span style="font-family: Courier, Serif">&lt;a href="http://domain.com/song.mp3"&gt;Link&lt;/a&gt;</span></label></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="postbox">
            <h3 class="hndle"><span>Tags</span></h3>
            <div class="inside">
                <ul>
                    <li>WPaudio will always convert <span style="font-family: Courier, Serif">[wpaudio]</span> tags, but it can also handle tags from other audio players.</li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_tag_audio"><input name="wpa_tag_audio" id="wpa_tag_audio" type="checkbox" <?php if ($wpa_options['wpa_tag_audio']) echo ' checked="yes"'; ?>>
                        Handle Audio Player tags - <span style="font-family: Courier, Serif">[audio:http://domain.com/song.mp3]</span></label></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="postbox">
            <h3 class="hndle"><span>Style</span></h3>
            <div class="inside">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="jQuery('.wpa_style_advanced').css('display', 'block');">It's not necessary to adjust these settings, but click here for advanced options.</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="wpa_style_advanced" style="display: none;">
                    <li>Optionally customize WPaudio's font</li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_style_text_font"><input type="text" name="wpa_style_text_font" id="wpa_style_text_font" value="<?php echo $wpa_options['wpa_style_text_font']; ?>"> Font face</label></li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_style_text_size"><input type="text" name="wpa_style_text_size" id="wpa_style_text_size" value="<?php echo $wpa_options['wpa_style_text_size']; ?>"> Font size</label></li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_style_text_weight"><select name="wpa_style_text_weight" id="wpa_style_text_weight">
                        <option value="inherit" <?php if ($wpa_options['wpa_style_text_weight'] == 'inherit') echo ' selected'; ?>>Inherit</option>
                        <option value="normal" <?php if ($wpa_options['wpa_style_text_weight'] == 'normal') echo ' selected'; ?>>Normal</option>
                        <option value="bold" <?php if ($wpa_options['wpa_style_text_weight'] == 'bold') echo ' selected'; ?>>Bold</option>
                        </select> Font weight</label></li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_style_text_letter_spacing"><input type="text" name="wpa_style_text_letter_spacing" id="wpa_style_text_letter_spacing" value="<?php echo $wpa_options['wpa_style_text_letter_spacing']; ?>"> Letter spacing</label></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="wpa_style_advanced" style="display: none;">
                    <li>Optionally customize colors (Most commonly 3 or 6 character <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#Color_table" target="_blank">hex codes</a>.  For example: <span style="font-family: Courier, Serif">#2244ff</span>)</li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_style_text_color"><input type="text" name="wpa_style_text_color" id="wpa_style_text_color" value="<?php echo $wpa_options['wpa_style_text_color']; ?>" size="7"> Text color</label></li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_style_link_color"><input type="text" name="wpa_style_link_color" id="wpa_style_link_color" value="<?php echo $wpa_options['wpa_style_link_color']; ?>" size="7"> Link color</label></li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_style_link_hover_color"><input type="text" name="wpa_style_link_hover_color" id="wpa_style_link_hover_color" value="<?php echo $wpa_options['wpa_style_link_hover_color']; ?>" size="7"> Link hover color</label></li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_style_bar_base_bg"><input type="text" name="wpa_style_bar_base_bg" id="wpa_style_bar_base_bg" value="<?php echo $wpa_options['wpa_style_bar_base_bg']; ?>" size="7"> Bar base background</label></li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_style_bar_load_bg"><input type="text" name="wpa_style_bar_load_bg" id="wpa_style_bar_load_bg" value="<?php echo $wpa_options['wpa_style_bar_load_bg']; ?>" size="7"> Bar load background</label></li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_style_bar_position_bg"><input type="text" name="wpa_style_bar_position_bg" id="wpa_style_bar_position_bg" value="<?php echo $wpa_options['wpa_style_bar_position_bg']; ?>" size="7"> Bar position background</label></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="postbox">
            <h3 class="hndle"><span>Notification</span></h3>
            <div class="inside">
                <ul>
                    <li>I love seeing who's using my plugin!  Please select this option to enable a notification when a post containing the player is published so I can come check out your site.  Your blog may even be featured on WPaudio.com.  Thanks!</li>
                    <li><label for="wpa_track_permalink"><input name="wpa_track_permalink" id="wpa_track_permalink" type="checkbox" <?php if ($wpa_options['wpa_track_permalink']) echo ' checked="yes"'; ?>>
                        Allow WPaudio notification</label></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p class="submit">
    <input class="button-primary" type="submit" value="Save Changes">
</p>

</form>
</div>
<!-- wpa menu end -->
<?php
}

## WP new post - add ping if contains wpaudio
function wpaPostNew($id) {
    $post = get_post($id);
    if (strpos(strtolower($post->post_content), 'wpaudio') !== false) {
        $permalink = rawurlencode(get_permalink($id));
        if (function_exists('curl_init') && function_exists('curl_setopt') && function_exists('curl_exec') && function_exists('curl_close')) {
            $ch = curl_init("http://wpaudio.com/t/?url_post=$permalink");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: How are the audio players served? I'd look at the "degradable html5 audio" elements you have as a starting point. If it's just standard content do you get these issues?

Comment: there are audio players on the blog homepage www.eslangel.com that work fine. Those aren't hidden with css.  The audio players are served by a plugin, with flash or html5 chosen depending on the browser.

Comment: What about the php that generates your page? The plugin code you pasted is only used to set up the plugin.

Comment: @John Kalberer it's a self-hosted Wordpress blog with a premium theme called Thesis.There's a lot of files but I'm not familiar enough with them to even know if it's the premium theme or the wordpress blog that generates the page. I only touch the custom functions file to add custom functions.

Comment: which version of IE is not working? none of them?

Comment: @karameloso none of them. However, IE works on the homepage audio players (at www.eslangel.com) where no javascript is involved, but not in the game ( www.eslangel.com/michaels-numbers-game ).

Comment: it works for me in ie9, but not in the rest..

Answer (score 3):

> Can anyone help me debug this in IE or give me an idea how to debug it in IE?

If you're on at least IE8, the [developer tools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/03/07/improved-productivity-through-internet-explorer-8-developer-tools.aspx) are helpful. They're [even better in IE9](http://www.sitepoint.com/debug-faster-with-f12-developer-tools-in-internet-explorer-9/). As long as you've got the developer console open, sprinkling `console.log` statements around can help find what line(s) your code is borking on. Be careful to remove then once you're done though - `console.log` [breaks IE](http://www.thorntechnologies.com/2011/07/internet-explorer-and-console-log-woes/) if you have the developer window closed.

> I also noticed that in I.E. the page takes a heck of a long time to load (5 minutes later, It still says 16 items remaining at the bottom). I assume those might be the audio players. In other browswers, that doesn't happen.

I've got a hunch this is the main cause of your problems. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) should help show you what network requests are still waiting, as will the [network tab](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/04/22/ie9-developer-tools-network-tab.aspx) in the IE9 developer tools

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you're calling them with a `click` function? What happens if you use a `live` function instead?

```
function test() {
   $('.start').live('click', function() {
      ran = getRandom(myArray, true);
      if ($('#ONE').length) { 
         $( '#' + ran ).show();
      } 
      else { 
         $('#f-' + ran).css('display', 'block');
      };
});
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I copied your code in and it didn't work in any browser.

Comment: I see you've edited it, I'll try again. ...Sadly, still doesn't work in any browswer

Comment: It should just replace from `$(".start").click(function(){...` to the end of the `else` statement. If that doesn't work I'll take a further look into it and see if I can solve the problem.

Comment: o.k, thanks,  it works in Chrome and Firefox, but still not in IE. No matter which code, IE never seems to finish loading. It says 16 items remaining at the bottom...

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `display` property to empty:

```
.css('display', '')
```

Comment: @Michael: Have you tried using the `visibility` property instead of `display`?

Comment: @Michael: Did you change the CSS from "display:none" to "visibility:hidden"?

Answer (score 0):

Alright... based off your source I got it "functioning" although your probably want to consolidate your [script](http://jsfiddle.net/Ptuq8/1/)

Here is the minor change to the html (beside moving the script out)

```
<div class="audio_wrap html5audio">
    <div id="f-ONE" style="display: none;">
        <a href="http://eslangel.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/one2.mp3" title="Click to open"
            id="f-ONE">Audio MP3</a></div>
    <audio controls autobuffer id="ONE" class="html5audio"><source src="http://eslangel.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/one2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <a href="http://eslangel.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/07/one2.mp3" title="Click to open" id="f-ONE">Audio MP3</a>
    </audio>
</div>
```

You can see that I gave the inner div an id of "f-ONE".  You will need to do this for all divs.  This markup could definitely be cleaned up.

Then I modified this script:

```
// see if the canvas element is supported so we know it's html5
if (!!document.createElement('canvas').getContext) {
    jQuery("div.audio_wrap div").remove();
} else {
    jQuery("audio").remove();
    jQuery("div.audio_wrap div").show();
}
```

So I remove your audio tags when it is not supported by the browser.  I am pretty sure this is the root of your problem since the player was not degrading gracefully.  Maybe the anchor tag "f-ONE" was supposed to be outside of the audio element?

Comment: hmm, thanks, however, the html is created by a wordpress audio plugin and the ids I believe are dynamically generated so i can't go in and do changes without altering the php which is complex (for me)

Comment: thanks for the script consolidation by the way! that's great.

Comment: Well this solution works.  Could you post more info on how the page is generated?  The whole markup including the php would work.

Comment: I updated the OP with the PHP file from the audio plugin. I think this is responsible for all of the page generation, but I'm a bit of a newbie so I may be wrong.

Comment: it's a self-hosted Wordpress blog with a premium theme called Thesis.There's a lot of files but I'm not familiar enough with them to even know if it's the premium theme or the wordpress blog that generates the page. I only touch the custom functions file to add custom functions.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually not a JavaScript problem.

For some reason, when the server side code detects an IE client, it serves audio in HTML5 format ("audio" tag) when it should give the browser a Flash file. Unfortunately, out of the major browsers, IE has the most terrible support for HTML5; your audio file was never understood/loaded in the first place.

On the other hand, Firefox, which supports HTML5, is given a Flash audio player. Somewhere in your server code, there is a conditional statement that needs to be reversed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure that's true? If you check the blog home page ( www.eslangel.com ) in internet explorer, there are audio players that do appear and work (those audio players aren't goverened by the same javascript).  It's something about the introduction of the javascript (or how i've written the javascript) in the game that's causing them not to appear...

Comment: I forgot to mention I was using IE8. With IE8 I can only see a link to the mp3 file. No audio player appears.


Unlike previous versions of IE8, IE9 does support the HTML5 audio tag (you're probably using IE9). Still, only version 9 works, which means when you encounter an IE client, it's best to serve the Flash version of the audio player.


Could you give me the link to audio plugin's home page? Maybe I could work something out.

Comment: On the blog homepage, www.eslangel.com I can view the audio player with internet  explorer 8, and so can my friend.  However, in the game, we can't view the audio players with i.e. 8. I think it's because the way I wrote the javascript with the ids... Anyways, here's the plugin homepage http://soukie.net/degradable-html5-audio-and-video-plugin/

Comment: At [html5media.info](http://html5media.info/) you will find instructions on how to enable HTML5 audio tags for all browsers (simply adding a script link in the head of your document). Let me know if it works.

Comment: o.k, it solves one problem but creates another. it seems as if HTML5 was the issue, but now with that link in the header all the audio players appear at once and start playing automatically, so none of the other JavaScript works that keeps them hidden. Also, it's much better if there's a manual start rather than an automatic play.

Answer (score 0):

So if all the audio files are visible initially, they play fine?

If that is the case, can you just set the width/height to 0px and expand it when a selection is made?

Comment: that might be an idea to test, thanks.  The problem is/might be that the javascript was written a certain way for Firefox browswer to accommodate the plugin's demand that firefox use Flash. It seems as if the Javascript I wrote to fix that is now making IE use HTML5, so expanding width/height to 0px in the current state won't change anything. But as long as I can get that to work for all browswers, it might be the solution. Thanks